# Unicode strings in process memory

Tags: x86, language-design, language-implementation

What is the most preferred format of unicode strings in memory when they are being processed? And why?

I am implementing a programming language by producing an executable file image for it. Obviously a working programming language implementation requires a protocol for processing strings.

I've thought about using dynamic arrays as the basis for strings because they are very simple to implement and very efficient for short strings. I just have no idea about the best possible format for characters when using strings in this manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UTF16 is the most widely used format.

The advantage of [UTF16](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) over [UTF8](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is that, despite being less compact, every character has a constant size of 2bytes (16bits) - as long as you don't use surrogates (when sticking to 2bytes chars, the encoding is called [UCS-2](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/CEI_10646)).

In UTF8 there is only a small set of characters coded on 1bytes, others are up 4 bytes. This makes character processing less direct and more error prone.

Of course using Unicode is preferred since it enables to handle international characters.

Comment: Unicode has 1,112,064 valid code-points,
 so [UTF-16 is variable-width: 1 or 2 chunks of 16 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).  According to Wikipedia, the single-chunk subset of UTF-16 is really not sufficient: "As of Unicode 9.0 some modern non-latin Asian, Middle-eastern and African scripts fall outside this range, as do most emoji characters"

Answer (score 4):

The C Python 2.x series used UTF-16 and UCS-4 depending on platform/build/etc.

[Here's an interesting discussion](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2006-September/003795.html) from python-dev on the requirements and trade-offs in choosing the Unicode internal representation for Python 3.0. While there's more content there than I can briefly describe, it includes:

- Discussing the external interface (constant time slicing, efficient implementations of .lower, .islower, etc.)
- External requirements (GTK takes UTF-8 strings, QT takes UTF-16 and UCS-4 strings, Windows takes UT-16 strings, etc.)
- It points at other implementations of Unicode data (eg. QT's).
- It discusses important use cases (which is closely related to external interface).
- etc.